# Binding Combobox with database

Tags: c#, combobox

I have combobox in my form which display value from database. I want one default value so I use `.text` property also and on selected index changed event the label display the corresponding value of the database the code is not working

```
string cstr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Test"].ConnectionString;

private void AddStock_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   bindcombo();
}

private void bindcombo()
{
   SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cstr);
   SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Dname FROM dealer", con);

   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   da.Fill(dt);

   cmbdealer.DataSource = dt;
   cmbdealer.DisplayMember = "Dname";
   cmbdealer.Text = "select-Dealer";

   con.Close();
}

private void cmbdealer_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   dealerdetails();
}

private void dealerdetails()
{
   SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cstr);
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from dealer where Dname='" + cmbdealer.Text + "'", con);
   con.Open();
   SqlDataReader re = cmd.ExecuteReader();
   while (re.Read())
   {
     lbdl.Text = re["Ddlno"].ToString();
     lbgst.Text = re["Dgstno"].ToString();
     lbadd.Text = re["Daddress"].ToString();
   }
}
```

the above code is working fine but when the form is load all the 3 label shows the database value of the first entry of my dealer table without selecting and value from combobox.

Comment: You set `cmbdealer.Text` to ` "select-Dealer"`, so in where condition it selects the first one

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but _please_ read up on SQL-injection. Just imagine what would happen if somebody managed to submit your form with cmbdealer.Text set to `a'; drop table dealer;`

Comment: Can you explain exactly what is not working in the code above?

Comment: what i want is when user select a particular dealer name from combobox  all the information of that dealer will display on my labels, but when the form is loaded combobox display its default text   " Select Dealer "   but all the lable display the data from the first row of dealer table

Comment: Did you set somewhere the SelectedIndex property? I cannot reproduce this problem. Is this a WinForms application ? Also there is no way to show that "Select - Dealer" text when the combo is binded to a datasource in this way.

Comment: i have not set the selectedIndex property. yes this is winForms